# LinkedIn Connections List code is Required for android application

Tags: list, linkedin-api, connection

I am new In android and currently working on a project which shows different friend list of different social network.
But Here at the stage I am fail to get LinkedIn Connections List and I have searched rest of the Internet but couldn't find any way. . .

If anyone know the code please help me. . . thanks in advance. .

Cheer!

Sample code is here Bellow. . .

```
final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
        .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(
                Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET, Config.scopeParams);
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
        .newInstance(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,
                Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
LinkedInApiClient client;
LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = null;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    }
    share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_share);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linkedInLogin();
        }
    });

    // share on linkedin
    share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String share = et.getText().toString();
            if (null != share && !share.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");
                try {
                    consumer.sign(post);
                } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } // here need the consumer for sign in for post the share
                post.setHeader("content-type", "text/XML");
                String myEntity = "<share><comment>"+ share +"</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";
                try {
                    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(myEntity));
                    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
                    Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                            "Shared sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                        "Please enter the text to share",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            /*String share = et.getText().toString();
            if (null != share && !share.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                client.postNetworkUpdate(share);
                et.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                        "Shared sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                        "Please enter the text to share",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
        }
    });
}

private void linkedInLogin() {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
            LinkedInSampleActivity.this);

    LinkedinDialog d = new LinkedinDialog(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
            progressDialog);
    d.show();

    // set call back listener to get oauth_verifier value
    d.setVerifierListener(new OnVerifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVerify(String verifier) {
            try {
                Log.i("LinkedinSample", "verifier: " + verifier);

                accessToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService
                        .getOAuthAccessToken(LinkedinDialog.liToken,
                                verifier);
                LinkedinDialog.factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                // client.postNetworkUpdate("Testing by Mukesh!!! LinkedIn wall post from Android app");
                Log.i("LinkedinSample",
                        "ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                Log.i("LinkedinSample",
                        "ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
                name.setText("Welcome " + p.getFirstName() + " "
                        + p.getLastName());
                name.setVisibility(0);
                login.setVisibility(4);
                share.setVisibility(0);
                et.setVisibility(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("LinkedinSample", "error to get verifier");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // set progress dialog
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this get user-Connections

```
        public class LinkCon_Main extends BaseActivityListView {

    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
            .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(Config.CONSUMER_KEY,
                    Config.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
            .newInstance(Config.CONSUMER_KEY, Config.CONSUMER_SECRET);


    ProgressDialog mPrograss;
    String name;
    View experiencePage;

    TextView prof_Name, prof_Headline, prof_Location, prof_Industry;

    String prof_name, prof_headline, prof_location, prof_industry, prof_summary, prof_experience,prof_education,prof_languages,prof_skills, prof_interests,prof_birthdate,prof_contatct,prof_email;
    String con_name, con_headline, con_location,con_industry, con_summary,con_experience,con_education,con_languages,con_skills,con_interets,con_birthdate,con_phone;
    Connections con_email;
    String pic_url,con_pic_url;
    String startDate, endDate;
    String item;
    String dty;
    String dtm;
    String dtd;


    ImageView person_Pic, con_pic;

    Map<SearchParameter, String> searchParameters;

    ListView connections_list;
    ArrayList<Person> itemslist;



    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    Iterator localIterator;

    Person mylist;
    RelativeLayout  layout_persondetils,layout_con_profile;
    LinkedInApiClient client;
    Person person;
    Connections connections;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    LinkConApp myLinkCon;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String[] months= {"Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May","June", "July", "August","Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    StringBuilder localStringBuilder;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLinkCon=new LinkConApp();
        prof_Name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        prof_Headline=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_headline);
        prof_Location=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_Location);
        prof_Industry=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_industry);
        person_Pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        layout_persondetils=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_profiledetils);
        layout_con_profile=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_con_profile);

        layout_persondetils.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userpersons();
            }
        });

        mPrograss=new ProgressDialog(LinkCon_Main.this);
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // ImageLoader options
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.photo)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher).cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true).build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));

        connections_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.connectionslist);

        itemslist = new ArrayList<Person>();

        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        }


        final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Config.OAUTH_PREF,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String token = pref.getString(Config.PREF_TOKEN, null);
        final String tokenSecret = pref.getString(Config.PREF_TOKENSECRET, null);

        if (token == null || tokenSecret == null) {
            startAutheniticate();
        } else {
            showCurrentUser(new LinkedInAccessToken(token, tokenSecret));
        }


    }

    void startAutheniticate() {
        mPrograss.setMessage("Loading...");
        mPrograss.setCancelable(true);
        mPrograss.show();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, LinkedInRequestToken>() {

            @Override
            protected LinkedInRequestToken doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(LinkedInRequestToken liToken) {
                final String uri = liToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
                getSharedPreferences(Config.OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET,
                        liToken.getTokenSecret()).commit();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }.execute();
        mPrograss.dismiss();
    }


    void finishAuthenticate(final Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
            final String problem = uri.getQueryParameter(Config.OAUTH_QUERY_PROBLEM);
            if (problem == null) {

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, LinkedInAccessToken>() {

                    @Override
                    protected LinkedInAccessToken doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(
                                Config.OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService
                                .getOAuthAccessToken(
                                        new LinkedInRequestToken(
                                                uri.getQueryParameter(Config.OAUTH_QUERY_TOKEN),
                                                pref.getString(
                                                        Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET,
                                                        null)),
                                                        uri.getQueryParameter(Config.OAUTH_QUERY_VERIFIER));
                        pref.edit()
                        .putString(Config.PREF_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken())
                        .putString(Config.PREF_TOKENSECRET,
                                accessToken.getTokenSecret())
                                .remove(Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET).commit();
                        return accessToken;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedInAccessToken accessToken) {
                        mPrograss.dismiss();
                        showCurrentUser(accessToken);
                    }
                }.execute();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Appliaction down due OAuth problem: " + problem,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

        }
    }

    void clearTokens() {
        getSharedPreferences(Config.OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        .remove(Config.PREF_TOKEN).remove(Config.PREF_TOKENSECRET)
        .remove(Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET).commit();
    }


    void showCurrentUser(final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken) {

        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
        mPrograss.setMessage("Loading..");
        mPrograss.show();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>() {


            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    final Person user_Profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID)); 
                    person = client.getProfileById(user_Profile.getId(), EnumSet.of(
                            ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                            ProfileField.LAST_NAME,
                            ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,
                            ProfileField.INDUSTRY,
                            ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS,
                            ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                            ProfileField.SUMMARY,
                            ProfileField.POSITIONS,
                            ProfileField.EDUCATIONS,
                            ProfileField.LANGUAGES,
                            ProfileField.SKILLS,
                            ProfileField.INTERESTS,
                            ProfileField.PHONE_NUMBERS,
                            ProfileField.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                            ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
                            ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL));


                    prof_name       = person.getFirstName() + " "   + person.getLastName();
                    prof_headline   = person.getHeadline();
                    prof_location   = person.getMainAddress();
                    prof_industry   = person.getIndustry();


                    return person;

                } catch (LinkedInApiClientException ex) {
                    return ex;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                if (result instanceof Exception) {
                    //result is an Exception :) 
                    final Exception ex = (Exception) result;
                    clearTokens();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            LinkCon_Main.this,
                            "Appliaction down due LinkedInApiClientException: "
                                    + ex.getMessage()
                                    + " Authokens cleared - try run application again.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else if (result instanceof Person) {

                    final Person person = (Person) result;

                    prof_Name.setText( person.getFirstName() + " "  + person.getLastName());
                    prof_Headline.setText(person.getHeadline());
                    prof_Location.setText(person.getMainAddress());
                    prof_Industry.setText(person.getIndustry());

                    prof_Name.setVisibility(0);
                    prof_Headline.setVisibility(0);
                    prof_Location.setVisibility(0);
                    prof_Industry.setVisibility(0);
                    person_Pic.setVisibility(0);

                    userConnections();
                    userDetails();



                }


            }
        }.execute();
        mPrograss.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        finishAuthenticate(intent.getData());
    }



    public void userDetails(){


        if(person.getPictureUrl()!=null){
            pic_url = person.getPictureUrl().toString();
            imageLoader.displayImage(pic_url, person_Pic);                  
        }else{
            person_Pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);    
        }

        /*************** person Details Summary/experience/education/languages/skills/contacts/interests **********************/

        if (person.getSummary()!=null) {
            prof_summary    = person.getSummary();
        }

        prof_experience="";
        for (Position position:person.getPositions().getPositionList())
        {
            if(position.isIsCurrent()){
                startDate=months[(int) (position.getStartDate().getMonth()-1)]+"-"+position.getStartDate().getYear();
                endDate="Currently Working";
            }else{
                startDate=months[(int) (position.getStartDate().getMonth()-1)]+"-"+position.getStartDate().getYear();
                endDate=months[(int) (position.getEndDate().getMonth()-1)]+"-"+position.getEndDate().getYear();
            }
            prof_experience=prof_experience+"<b>" +"Position :"+"</b>"+position.getTitle()+"<br><b>" +"Company :"+ "</b>"+ position.getCompany().getName()+"<br><b>" +"Start Date:"+ "</b>"+ startDate +"<br><b>" +"End Date:"+ "</b>"+ endDate +"<br>"+"<br>";
        }

        prof_education="";
        for (Education education:person.getEducations().getEducationList()) 
        {
            prof_education=prof_education +"<b>" +"Gaduation :"+ "</b>" +education.getDegree()+"<br><b>" +"Institute :"+ "</b>" +education.getSchoolName()+ "<br><b>" +"Graduation Year :"+ "</b>" +education.getEndDate().getYear()+"<br>"+"<br>";
        }
        prof_languages="";
        for(Language language:person.getLanguages().getLanguageList())
        {
            prof_languages=prof_languages+language.getLanguage().getName()+"\n";
        }

        prof_skills="";
        for(Skill skill:person.getSkills().getSkillList())
        {
            prof_skills=prof_skills+skill.getSkill().getName()+"\n";
        }


        prof_contatct="";
        PhoneNumbers contactinfo=person.getPhoneNumbers();
        if(contactinfo!=null ){
            for(PhoneNumber phoneno:person.getPhoneNumbers().getPhoneNumberList())
            {
                prof_contatct=prof_contatct+ phoneno.getPhoneNumber().toString();
            }
        }

        if(person.getEmailAddress()!=null){
            prof_email=person.getEmailAddress();
        }
        prof_interests = person.getInterests();
        prof_birthdate= person.getDateOfBirth().getDay()+"-"+ months[(int) (person.getDateOfBirth().getMonth()-1)]+"-"+person.getDateOfBirth().getYear();



    }


    public void userConnections(){
        final Set<ProfileField> connectionFields = EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID, 
                ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, 
                ProfileField.LAST_NAME, 
                ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                ProfileField.INDUSTRY,
                ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,

                ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS,
                ProfileField.LOCATION,
                ProfileField.LOCATION_COUNTRY, 
                ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME,

                ProfileField.SUMMARY,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS_DEGREE,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS_END_DATE,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS_FIELD_OF_STUDY,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS_ID,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS_SCHOOL_NAME,
                ProfileField.EDUCATIONS_START_DATE,

                ProfileField.LANGUAGES,
                ProfileField.LANGUAGES_ID,
                ProfileField.LANGUAGES_LANGUAGE,
                ProfileField.LANGUAGES_LANGUAGE_NAME,

                ProfileField.POSITIONS,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_COMPANY,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_COMPANY_INDUSTRY,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_COMPANY_NAME,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_END_DATE,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_IS_CURRENT,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_START_DATE,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_SUMMARY,
                ProfileField.POSITIONS_TITLE,

                ProfileField.SKILLS,
                ProfileField.INTERESTS,
                ProfileField.PHONE_NUMBERS,
                ProfileField.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
                ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL
                );

        connections = client.getConnectionsForCurrentUser(connectionFields);

        for (Person person : connections.getPersonList()) {
            itemslist.add(person);
        }

        connection_Adapter myadpter=new connection_Adapter();
        connections_list.setAdapter(myadpter);
        connections_list.setVisibility(0);
        connections_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                /*Connections List item position selection*/
                person = itemslist.get(position);
/*
                Map<SearchParameter, String> searchParameters = new EnumMap<SearchParameter, String>(SearchParameter.class);
                 searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.KEYWORDS, "University of X");        

                 People people = client.searchPeople(searchParameters);
                 System.out.println("Total search result:" + people.getCount());

                 for (Person person : people.getPersonList()) {
                     System.out.println(person.getId() + ":" + person.getFirstName() + " " +
                     person.getLastName() + ":" + person.getHeadline());
                 }*/


                /*
                People people = client.searchPeople(searchParameters);
                for (Person persons : people.getPersonList()) {
                    persons = client.getProfileByApiRequest(persons.getApiStandardProfileRequest());
                }
                Log.i("My Persons list", ""+person);*/

                /*Intent mycon=new Intent(LinkCon_Main.this, Con_Profile.class);
                mycon.putExtra("conid", con_name);
                startActivity(mycon);
*/

                con_name=person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName();
                System.out.println("Name:"+con_name);

                con_headline=person.getHeadline();
                System.out.println("Designation:"+con_headline);

                con_industry=person.getIndustry();
                System.out.println("Industry:"+con_industry);

                Location localLocation = person.getLocation();
                if (localLocation != null){
                    con_location=String.format("%s", new Object[] { localLocation.getName() });
                    System.out.println("Con_Loaction:"+con_location);
                }

                /*****PICTURE/NAME/INDUSTRY/LOCATION Tested OK******/

                /********need to get SUMMARY/EXPERIENCE/EDUCATION/SKILLS/LANGUAGES/DATEOFBIRTH/PHONENUMBER/EMAIL**********/

                Toast.makeText(LinkCon_Main.this, "Name:"+" "+con_name +"\n"+"Position:"+" "+con_headline+"\n"+"Industry:"+" "+con_industry+"\n"+"Locations:"+" "+con_location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }//onItemClick
        });
    }

    public class connection_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return itemslist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if(convertView==null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,
                        null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.con_Itenames = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.connection_name);
                holder.con_designations = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.connection_headline);
                holder.con_ItemImage = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.connection_image);
                holder.con_locationad = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.connection_location);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            SetData(holder,position);
            return convertView;
        }

        protected Context getBaseContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void SetData(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Person con_details = itemslist.get(position);
            holder.con_Itenames.setText(con_details.getFirstName()+" "+con_details.getLastName());
            holder.con_designations.setText(con_details.getIndustry());

            Location localLocation = con_details.getLocation();
            if (localLocation != null){
                con_location=String.format("%s", new Object[] { localLocation.getName() });
            }
            holder.con_locationad.setText(con_location);
            holder.con_Itenames.setTag(con_details);
            if (con_details.getPictureUrl()!=null) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(con_details.getPictureUrl(), holder.con_ItemImage, options);
            }else {
                holder.con_ItemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);}
        }

        public void setListItems(ArrayList<Person> newList) {
            itemslist = newList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }    
    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView con_Itenames,con_designations, con_locationad;
        ImageView con_ItemImage;
    }

    private void userpersons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent user_prof = new Intent(LinkCon_Main.this, User_Profile.class);

        user_prof.putExtra("pic", pic_url);
        user_prof.putExtra("name", prof_name);
        user_prof.putExtra("headline", prof_headline);
        user_prof.putExtra("locations", prof_location);
        user_prof.putExtra("industry", prof_industry);
        user_prof.putExtra("summary", prof_summary);
        user_prof.putExtra("languages", prof_languages);
        user_prof.putExtra("experience", prof_experience);
        user_prof.putExtra("education", prof_education);
        user_prof.putExtra("skills", prof_skills);
        user_prof.putExtra("interests", prof_interests);
        user_prof.putExtra("dateofbirth", prof_birthdate);
        user_prof.putExtra("phoneno", prof_contatct);
        user_prof.putExtra("email", prof_email);

        startActivity(user_prof);       
}


}
```